# pandas diff() ignores groupby

Tags: python, pandas

First of all, apologies if this has been solved somewhere. I have gone through these posts [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347497/pandas-groupby-diff), [b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48888843/pandas-use-diff-with-groupby) and they do not seem to address my problem.

#### For several objects, I want to calculate parameter differences in time, and sum them up.

#### synthetic data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(23)

dict_1 = {
    'time': range(100), 
    'object': [1]*100, 
    'parameter_1':np.random.randint(-10,10,100),
    'parameter_2':np.random.randint(-10,10,100)}

dict_2 = {
    'time': range(100), 
    'object': [2]*100, 
    'parameter_1':np.random.randint(-120,-110,100),
    'parameter_2':np.random.randint(-10,10,100)}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_2)

df = df1.append(df2)
```

#### approach:

using `groupby`, `agg`, and `diff`:

for df1:

```
diffs = df1.groupby(['object', 'time']).agg({'parameter_1': np.mean, 'parameter_2': np.mean}).diff()
diffs['total_variation'] = abs(diffs['parameter_1']) + abs(diffs['parameter_2'])
np.max(diffs['total_variation'])

output: 35
```

for df2:

```
diffs = df2.groupby(['object', 'time']).agg({'parameter_1': np.mean, 'parameter_2': np.mean}).diff()
diffs['total_variation'] = abs(diffs['parameter_1']) + abs(diffs['parameter_2'])
np.max(diffs['total_variation'])

output: 24
```

for the combined data:

```
diffs = df.groupby(['object', 'time']).agg({'parameter_1': np.mean, 'parameter_2': np.mean}).diff()
diffs['total_variation'] = abs(diffs['parameter_1']) + abs(diffs['parameter_2'])
np.max(diffs['total_variation'])
```

#### expected result:

35

#### actual result:

129

So, it seems that `diff()` ignores the grouping. 
I could write a solution for this that involves for-loops, but since my data is on the large side, I would rather avoid that. Is there a way to fix this, or am I misusing the functions?

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: when using a grouped diff I use [`np.diff()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) if i do not want a transformed output, rather a grouped difference. :)

Comment: looks like expected behaviour tbh